# Java Record Navigation

Tags: java, user-interface, button, record

your valuable help needed again. I have the following code in which i am reading file contents for each file. each file is related to an individual staff. On click of a button called "show staff record", i want to show all staff file data in a GUI. but instead of all them appearing at one i want it to have navigation next and previous like in MS Access? any ideas. a code perhaps?

```
/*********************Calculate Staff Balance***************************/   
public class calcBalanceListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            File folder = new File("/register/");
           filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                                for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                                    filePaths.add(file.getPath());
                                    }
            }

        }//end try

        catch (Exception f) {
            f.printStackTrace();
          } 

            callDetail();
            }}
```

/*************************************************************************/

```
public void callDetail() {


    File f = new File(filePaths.get(indexCounter));
    try{
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String name = bufferedReader.readLine();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        bufferedReader.readLine();
        String address = bufferedReader.readLine();
        int amount = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
        bufferedReader.readLine();

        balanceFrame = new JFrame("Monthly Staff Balance");

            lID.setText("Staff ID: " + id);
            lname.setText("Staff ID: " + name);
            laddress.setText("Staff ID: " + address);
            lbalance.setText("Staff ID: " + amount);


            balanceFrame.add(lID);
            balanceFrame.add(lname);
            balanceFrame.add(laddress);
            balanceFrame.add(lbalance);

        bufferedReader.close();
        fileReader.close();

    }//end try
    catch(IOException z){

        z.printStackTrace();
    }   //end catch     


}
```

/***************************************************************************************************/

Answer (score 2):

What you might do is that instead of reading the files, in your loop, you might want to iterate and obtain the file location of all the files in your directory and place their address inside an array list.

You can then use the back/forward buttons to traverse the array list, each time loading the file according to which location you are currently in your array list.

```
List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                        filePaths.add(file.getPath());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

All you need to do is to have some global counter which you use to then navigate the array list when the forward/backward buttons are pressed. Once the button is pressed, load the appropriate file (determined by the counter) and display its content.

Comment: can u demonstrate the global counter

Comment: @user1106130 The global counter is nothing more than a global variable. Please note that the purpose of this site is not for other people to make your work for you...

Comment: ok i have done the global counter "Myself". the arraylist element only hold path address, how do i print the actual file content?

Comment: Pressing the buttons should incremener/decrement the counter, you must also make sure that your counter never goes below zero or exceeds the size of the array list. In the same event listener that increments or decrements the counter, you should also be able to access the given element, using `File f = new File(filePaths.get(globalCounterValue);` and then render the content using the same code you currently have in your for loop.

Comment: ive updated the code, i dont know how and where to implement the gui and to display the contents of the file.