# Java arraylist navigation

Tags: java, user-interface, button, arraylist

Please help me correct my if statements. I am trying to navigate through the arraylist elements but in some cases next and previous button displays command line errors. the errors vary but they have in common the following...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index....
```

heres the code

```
public class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x){
        if (x.getSource() == nxtButton){
            indexCounter++;
            balanceFrame.setVisible(false);
            callDetail();

            if(indexCounter == filePaths.size()-1) { //max counter...we dont want to exceed the max number, size of array
                indexCounter = -1;
        }
    }
    else if (x.getSource() == prevButton){
        indexCounter--;
        balanceFrame.setVisible(false);
        callDetail();
        if(indexCounter == 0){
            indexCounter = filePaths.size()-1;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: you need to post the callDetail() method and complete stack trace.

Comment: You don't show the code where the list is accessed using the index, and you don't show the stack trace. The message isn't even complete. Read the stack trace: it has all the information you need to know where the problem occurs.

Comment: I am pretty sure that details about this questions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743187/java-record-navagation/8743232#8743232

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you are incrementing/decrementing the counter, access the ArrayList, and then, make the check.

What you need to do is to increment/decrement the counter, make the check, and then access the  ArrayList.

ArrayLists are have 0 based locations, so you need to make sure that the smallest location possible is 0 and that the maximum location possible is one less than the amount of items in the ArrayList.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
indexCounter++;
if (indexCounter > (filePaths.size - 1))
{
    indexCounter = filePaths.size - 1;
}
callDetail();
```

and in your second part

```
indexCounter--;
if (indexCounter < 0)
{
    indexCounter = 0;
}
callDetail();
```

This will cause the user to keep viewing the last record if he/she keeps pressing next and the first record if he/she keeps pressing previous.

On second note, you seem to want to implement a Circular list, so this should work:

```
indexCounter++;
if (indexCounter > (filePaths.size - 1))
{
    indexCounter = 0;
}
callDetail();
```

and in your second part

```
indexCounter--;
if (indexCounter < 0)
{
    indexCounter = filePaths.size - 1;
}
callDetail();
```

Comment: much appreciated...problem solved! yes i wanted a circular list. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit vague, but I think the problem is here:

```
indexCounter = -1;
```

I think what you actually wanted is:

```
indexCounter -= 1; // indexCounter = indexCounter - 1
```

Your if condition seems to wrong as well. It should be like this:

```
if (indexCounter == filePaths.size()) {
    indexCounter -= 1; // indexCounter = indexCounter - 1
}
```

Or even better:

```
if (indexCounter >= filePaths.size()) {
    indexCounter = filePaths.size() - 1;
}
```

Also, on a side note, in Java the convention is to use `CamelCase` for class names. So your class should be named `ButtonListener` and not `buttonListener`.

Comment: your if condition does not allow me to navigate further. so lets say, i am at arraylist index 0, clicking next takes me to 1 and then again to 2 (max size of array). clicking next again would create error as max size is reached. it need to go back to 0.