# Paginating an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, pagination

I am trying to create a simple pagination routine for values held in an `ArrayList`. Basically what I want to do is render the first five elements in the `ArrayList` at first go. And then when users click on `Next (increment by another 5)` and `Previous (decrease by 5)`.

My logic looks like this:

```
class foo
{
   private static final int defaultStep = 5;
   private int moveCounter;
   private List<String> values;

   public foo()
   {
     values = new ArrayList<String>();
     values.add("Fiber Channel");
     values.add("Copper Channel");
     ...
   }

  private void pageNext()
  {
   if (moveCounter > -1 && moveCounter < values.size())
   {
    int currentIndex = (moveCounter + 1);
    renderValues(currentIndex, false);
   }
  }

  private void pagePrevious()
  {
   if (moveCounter > -1 && moveCounter <= values.size())
   {
    renderValues(moveCounter-1, true);
   }
  }

 private void renderValues(int startIndex, boolean isPreviousCall)
 {
  if (startIndex > -1)
  {
   StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
   List<String> valuesToRender = new ArrayList<String>();
   int checkSteps = 1;
   while (startIndex < values.size())
   {
     valuesToRender.add(values.get(startIndex));
     if (checkSteps == defaultStep) break;
     startIndex++;
     checkSteps++;
   }
   moveCounter = startIndex;

   //TODO: Build html String
   ...
   }
 }
}
```

I have an issue with `pagePrevious` call, can you guys help me build the `valuesToRender` **5-steps** up `values array` before adding the value to render to the `valuesToRender` array.

I tried doing something like this also:

```
  for (int start = startIndex, end = values.size() - 1; start < end; start++, end--)
  {
    if (isPreviousCall) valuesToRender.add(values.get(end));
    else valuesToRender.add(values.get(start));

    if (checkSteps == defaultStep) break;
    checkSteps++;
  }
```

But this doesn't seems to work neither. Can you guys spot and help me fix this issue.
Thanks Guys.

Comment: Check this. It may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755619/java-arraylist-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

I'm not sure what renderValues does, and whether we have to substract 1 or maybe defaultStep from the upper bound of the moveCounter.

```
private void pageMove (int step)
{
    moveCounter = moveCounter + step;
    if (moveCounter < 0) moveCounter = 0;
    if (moveCounter > values.size ()) moveCounter = values.size ();
    renderValues (currentIndex, false);
}

private void pageNext ()
{
    pageMove (defaultStep);
}

private void pagePrevious ()
{
    pageMove (-defaultStep);
}
```

The first 3 lines could be packed into two big ternary experssions like so:

```
mc = ((mc + s) < 0) ? 0 : ((mc + s) > vs) ? vs : (mc + s);
```

but the 3 lines solution is better to follow.

Comment: Doing it this way, would `renderValues(..)` stay as it is or you think the second option stands fit - or perhaps needs changing?!

Comment: Well, I don't understand what 'renderValues' is doing. The variable names are quiete confusing. StartIndex and checkSteps are mutable? Maybe you better name them i or n. I thought the job of pagePrev is to set the scope somehow back - from 17-22 to 12-17 for example, and to check for boundary violation (prevent -3). The later work of layout is done in renderValues. Make short methods which have only one task to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Based on "pscuderi" [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22947052/1124409) 
I've built a wrapping class that can be helpful for someone looking for this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PaginatedList<T> {

private static final int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10;

private List<T> list;
private List<List<T>> listOfPages;
private int pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
private int currentPage = 0;

public PaginatedList(List<T> list) {
    this.list = list;
    initPages();
}

public PaginatedList(List<T> list, int pageSize) {
    this.list = list;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    initPages();
}

public List<T> getPage(int pageNumber) {
    if (listOfPages == null || 
        pageNumber > listOfPages.size() ||
        pageNumber < 1) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    currentPage = pageNumber;
    List<T> page = listOfPages.get(--pageNumber);
    return page;
}

public int numberOfPages() {
    if (listOfPages == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    return listOfPages.size();
}

public List<T> nextPage() {
    List<T> page = getPage(++currentPage);
    return page;
}

public List<T> previousPage() {
    List<T> page = getPage(--currentPage);
    return page;
}

public void initPages() {
    if (list == null || listOfPages != null) {
        return;
    }

    if (pageSize <= 0 || pageSize > list.size()) {
        pageSize = list.size();
    }

    int numOfPages = (int) Math.ceil((double) list.size() / (double) pageSize);
    listOfPages = new ArrayList<List<T>>(numOfPages);
    for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < numOfPages;) {
        int from = pageNum * pageSize;
        int to = Math.min(++pageNum * pageSize, list.size());
        listOfPages.add(list.subList(from, to));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 62; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    PaginatedList<Integer> paginatedList = new PaginatedList<Integer>(list);
    while (true) {
        List<Integer> page = paginatedList.nextPage();
        if (page == null || page.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }

        for (Integer value : page) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        System.out.println("------------");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (moveCounter > -1 && moveCounter <= archive.size())
{
  renderValues(moveCounter-1, true);
}
```

to

```
if (moveCounter > 0 && moveCounter <= archive.size())
{
  renderValues(moveCounter-1, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple java function for pagination. Note that the `page` starts from 0 (first page)

```
public List<Object> pagedResponse(List<Object> allItems, int page, int limit){
    int totalItems = allItems.size();
    int fromIndex = page*limit;
    int toIndex = fromIndex+limit;
    if(fromIndex <= totalItems) {
        if(toIndex > totalItems){
            toIndex = totalItems;
        }
        return allItems.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
    }else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<T>> partition = Lists.partition(list, pageSize);
```

Use the index as the page number to fetch page.