# How to make an "queued" for?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, queue

I have a list with 1000 objects and I want to go through it, but I don't want to read the 1000 objects at once, I want to read 10 objects per second (example) to avoid lags

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index = 0; index < objects.size(); index++) {
    
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22947052/2039546, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684194/2039546

Comment: Yes, it does. thank you